# HTML5 - Check if autoplay is allowed

Tags: javascript, html, audio

My website plays background music with autoplay. I made it use my custom controls for play and pause. Now, I'd like to set the initial state according to what is going on. If the music is about to play for real, it should show pause icon, otherwise (e.g. on mobile) play icon.

I would use `audio.paused` boolean value, but it's always false before the audio is loaded.

I would use `audio.autoplay` value, but it's always true for me, even on devices that don't support it.

Is there any clean way to know whether the audio *will be played*? I would like to keep it in sync with `autoplay` attribute, so if I decided to remove it, the state should always show play icon in the beginning.

Comment: __don't play background music especially not on autoplay__

Comment: There is whole bunch of sites where autoplaying background music is acceptable, for example music artists sites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just playing or even buffering songs isn't especially fair, when there is the slightest chance people can be on the site for other reasons, like for example to check for updates, to share the link. people can be on the page with a mobile network, with limited bandwidth and downloads of those sizes shouldn't ever start sneaky behind their back.

edit: a few additional references

Here is an overview over [the reasons not to have music on autoplay](http://www.zigpress.com/2009/10/30/10-reasons-websites-should-not-play-music/)

And contrary, a website I personally like a lot with a [great use of background music on autoplay](http://cabbibo.com/)

But if you are already building your own player and want that to be a feature of the page, setting that player to autoplay would not only devalue your own work, totally break your design. Instead you could just trust that people who want to hear the music will identify your audio player and use it.

To fully implement your custom player GUI you may want to listen for all audio events on the player element and update your view accordingly. The event you are looking for is "canplaythrough" but you probably want to react to at least most of the other events too. Those events are:

- [playing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/playing)
- [waiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/waiting)
- [seeking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/seeking)
- [seeked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/seeked)
- [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/ended)
- [loadedmetadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/loadedmetadata)
- [loadeddata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/loadeddata)
- [canplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/canplay)
- [canplaythrough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/canplaythrough)
- [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/timeupdate)
- [play](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/play)
- [pause](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/pause)
- [ratechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/ratechange)
- [volumechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/volumechange)
- [suspend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/suspend)
- [emptied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/emptied)
- [stalled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/stalled)

You currently may do something along the lines of

```
view.showPlayButton();
player.play();
```

but that breaks as soon as you at some point want to toggle your player in some other way or something else happens, like it gets stalled, so better listen to the event and update your GUI in one place, and control the playback (like start / stop the player) in another.

Comment: Thank you. I will look up those events. I don't agree with autoplaying being that bad. Most of the biggest music artists sites play music automatically and nobody complains. Mobiles usually have autoplaying property ignored, which is understandable.

Comment: some of my most favorite sites of all time have music on autoplay but that doesn't mean I agree with that practice or that I know a generally better solution other than being aware of that it can be a problem and always look for alternatives / discourage people from doing it.

Comment: Those are usually sites that need your attention anyway, you don't just open them to have them in the background. I'm not saying this practice should be followed by more sites, but there are some where it's absolutely reasonable :) I don't imagine sites like rainymood.com not autoplaying sounds.